# Add CSS and JS in AJAX-loaded PartialView

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

I found many answers about similar topics but all refers to PartialViews loaded not by AJAX where solutions are e.g. HtmlHelpers or Head section, but it doesn't work when I load PartialView by AJAX.

I wanna add CSS stylesheet and JS script inside AJAX-loaded PartialView. Now I coded it inside PartialView and it works but it's not good solution (include scripts and stylesheets inside body).

Comment: Can you load the css and js files with the main page load?

Comment: If it would be that easy ;) Sadly no ... e.g. I must add some jquery scripts which work on div that exist only in that PartialView, so if I add that script earlier in Layout, it will not work.

Comment: I didn't say it'd be easy, per se... :D If you encapsulate your css with selectors and your jQuery in functions, you could call the function in your callback, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know that earlier that using script tag inside body is not evil. So it's not that bad I thought at first.

I implemented two functions in cssLink.js which I include in head:

```
/// <reference path="../jquery-1.4.4.js" />

function addCssLink(link) {
    var _cssLink = '<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"' + link + '\" type=\"text/css\" />';
    $head = $('head');
    $link = $('link[href=' + link + ']', $head);
    if ($link.length == 0) {
        $head.append(_cssLink);
    }
}

function removeCssLink(link) {
    $('head link[href=' + link + ']').remove();
}
```

and I use those functions within PartialViews:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sideMenu').tabs('#content', '#content > *');
        addCssLink('/Content/SideMenu.css');
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        removeCssLink('/Content/SideMenu.css');
    });
</script>
```

Thank you guys for help, I think that informations about validation should be helpful for me later :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything should work just fine except validation. You need to tell jQuery about your new content on order to validate it. 
See 
[ASP.Net MVC: Can you use Data Annotations / Validation with an AJAX / jQuery call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825631/asp-net-mvc-can-you-use-data-annotations-validation-with-an-ajax-jquery-call)

Answer (score 0):

If you are only loading the PartialView once onto the page, there should be no problem including the scripts and CSS in the body. Like Adam said if you are including a HTML Form dynamically you just have to tell jQuery about it see here [ASP.Net MVC 3 client side validation with a dynamic form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272663/asp-net-mvc-3-client-side-validation-with-a-dynamic-form/5273930#5273930)

However if you want to include the same PartialView multiple times on to the page and do not want to load the script multiple times. Then there are dynamic script loaders you can use that:

- You can call just one from your main page, when you load the AJAX so that it is only included once
- Include a check to make sure the same script is not loaded multiple times.